# Scrolling text which is too long with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a music player/centre online.

I have a player that plays the music and displays the current track:

[image: The Player]

As you can see from th title of the song it is too long for the div. What i would like to do is scroll the text and reset it an rescroll etc.

I have attempted this with the below code:

html:

```
<div id="top-bar">
<div id="player-container">
        <div id="player">
          <div id="level1">
            <div class="current-track"><h1><span id="title">Party All Night (Sleep All Day) -</span> Sean Kingston</h1></div>
            <div class="add-to-playlist"></div>
            <div class="share"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div id="level2">
            <div class="current-time">0:00</div>
            <div class="progress"><span id="slider"></span></div>
            <div class="total-time">3:43</div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var scroll_text;
    $('div.current-track').hover(

    function() {
        var $elmt = $(this);
        scroll_text = setInterval(function() {
            scrollText($elmt);
        }, 5);
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(scroll_text);
        $(this).find('div.current-track h1').css({
            left: 0
        });
    });

    var scrollText = function($elmt) {
        var left = $elmt.find('div.current-track h1').position().left - 1;
        left = -left > $elmt.find('div.current-track h1').width() ? $elmt.find('div.current-track').width() : left;
        $elmt.find('div.current-track h1').css({
            left: left
        });
    };

});​​
```

Any pointer would be appriciated

Here is a jsfiddle for you guys:  [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/1/)

**UPDATE**

Could anybody tell me:

1. *How to make this happen automatically?* **Done**
2. *How to slow the scrolling?* **Done**

Here is the updated jsfiddle for you guys:  [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/14/)

Comment: do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Chrome console is showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null` which is most likely coming from `$elmt.find('div.current-track h1').position().left`

Comment: @EliranMalka Yes it does not scroll

Comment: Fx: $elmt.find("div.current-track h1").position() is null
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dn6jx/1/show/
Line 187

Comment: fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/6/ closing as too localized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how [jquery .find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) works:

```
$elmt.find('div.current-track h1')
```

should be:

```
$elmt.find('h1')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/5/

edit: updated fiddle for comments

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/15/

Comment: Great, 2 things: 1. how can i slow the scrolling and 2. how can i make it do it autoatically

Comment: 1. change the number of milliseconds you pass to setInterval (10 looks like a good speed to me) 2. move the setInterval outside of the hover event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Added check to see if text is long enough to require scrolling, removed the clear interval, and wrapped in plugin.

[JSFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/95/)

```
$.fn.scrolltxt = function() {
    var options = $.extend({
        speed : 28
    }, arguments[0] || {});

    return this.each(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if( el.find('span').width() > el.parent().width() ) {
            var scroll_text = setInterval(function() {
                scrollText();
            }, options.speed);
        };      

        var scrollText = function() {
            var width = el.width(),                
                left = el.position().left - 1;
            left = -left > width ? width : left;
            el.css({left: left});
        };
    });    };

$('.current-track h1').scrolltxt();
```

Comment: This is good but it would be better if it stopped scrolling when the end of the line became visible instead of scrolling right off the screen.

Comment: Really useful. You can run into trouble though, if you want to have more than one element using it. The problems you can run into: the interval has to be reset, if you populate the element with other text and the interval has to be linked to the specific element. Have a look at my answer here:

Answer (score 2):

A better way to animate the text (when the text is fully read => re-animate) :

[JSFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn6jx/289/)

```
$.fn.scrolltxt = function() {
    var options = $.extend({
        speed : 28
    }, arguments[0] || {});

    return this.each(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if( el.find('span').width() > el.parent().width() ) {
            var scroll_text = setInterval(function() {
                scrollText();
            }, options.speed);
        };      

        var scrollText = function() {
            var width = el.find('span').width(),
                left = el.position().left - 1;
            left = -left > width ? el.width() : left;
            el.css({left: left});
        };
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('.current-track h1').scrolltxt();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved the answer of Holiday Mat a bit.

If you want to replace the text with other text dynamically (which is not too long), the scrolling will still keeps place. You have to reset the interval somehow.

Another problem you might run into is, too many intervals are set and the text scrolls faster and faster.

Here a snippet which shows how I handled this. (I used h5 instead of h1, which you probably use somewhere else.) :

```js
$.fn.scrolltxt = function() {
  var options = $.extend({
speed: 28
  }, arguments[0] || {});

  return this.each(function() {
var $h5 = $(this);
var containerWidth = $h5.parent().width();
var textWidth = $h5.find('span').width();
var refreshIntervalId;

if (textWidth > containerWidth) {
  refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
    scrollText();
  }, options.speed);

  $h5.data('refreshIntervalId', refreshIntervalId);
} else {
  refreshIntervalId = $h5.data('refreshIntervalId');

  if (refreshIntervalId != undefined) {
    window.clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    $h5.removeData('refreshIntervalId');
  }
}

var scrollText = function() {
  var textWidth = $h5.find('span').width();
  var left = $h5.position().left - 1;
  left = -left > textWidth ? $h5.width() : left;
  $h5.css({
    left: left
  });
};
  });
};

$('h5.scroll').scrolltxt();
```

```css
#player {
  width: 500px;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.current-track {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.current-track h5 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="player">
  <div id="level1">
<div class="current-track">
  <h5 class="scroll"><span><strong>KAFKA (The artist formerly known as Prince)</strong></span></h5>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="current-track">
  <h5 class="scroll"><span>The Most Beautiful Girl In The World (original 1995 version)</span></h5>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or see the CodePen: https://codepen.io/r-w-c/pen/dyKoKQX